# JQuery/MVC selected option does nog change from script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In an MVC application I have two drop-down lists. The second gets populated based on the choice made in the first one. The 'start' value from the DB is pushed by the view to the second drop-down by setting a data-zatara-workyearid attribute. Updating the second one is done by the UpdateWorkYearDropDown() function. After loading the document I call this function to populate the second dropdown from the start on. So far so good.

The result :

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Work Year must be a number." data-val-required="The Work Year field is required." data-zatara-workyearid="6" id="WorkYearId" name="WorkYearId">
<option value="4">Boekjaar 2014</option>
<option value="5">Boekjaar 2015</option>
<option value="6">Boekjaar 2016</option>
</select>
```

In the $(document).ready function I try to set the selected value to the value stored in data-zatara-workyearid. Here it goes wrong. I have tried a dozen combination to get it working, none of them do work.
Pasting the code in the console does the job.

```
The full script :
function UpdateWordkYearDropDown() {
    var $id = $('#TenantId option:selected').attr('value');
    $('#WorkYearId').html('');
    $.getJSON('/ActivitiesAdmin/_WorkYearsForTenant/' + $id, function (data) {
    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
        $('#WorkYearId').append($('<option>', { text: item.Text, value: item.Value }));
    });
});
$('#LinkedStaffMemberFilter').attr('data-zatara-tenantid', $id);
$('.LinkedStaffMemberContainer').remove();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    UpdateWordkYearDropDown();
    var $WorkYearId = $('#WorkYearId').attr('data-zatara-workyearid');
    if (typeof $WorkYearId !== typeof undefined && $WorkYearId !== false) {
        $selectorstring = '#WorkYearId option[value="'+$WorkYearId+'"]';
        $($selectorstring).prop("selected", true);
    }
    else {
        console.log('atrr not found');
    }
});

$('#TenantId').change(function () { UpdateWordkYearDropDown(); });
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `#WorkYearId` drop-down is populated after the page is first loaded. But your document ready function only runs once, on first page load, so the selected value will not update when the drop-down is repopulated. Why not move the value-setting into the `UpdateWordkYearDropDown()` change function?

Comment: Your code is confusing. What is the purpose of `data-zatara-workyearid="6"`? Why are you trying to set the selected value of an option like that (as opposed to `$(#WorkYearId).val('6');`)?

Comment: @Jasen check-out the last line. I hook up the UpdateWorkYearDrowDown to the change event of the top dropdown. Thanx for the suggestion to put it all in the function which lead me to the actual solution.

Comment: @Stephen the purpose of the data- attribute is to be able to pass the original value from the db to the View. fyi .val() did not work eather.

Comment: The value of `data-zatara-workyearid` is `6` are your sure one of the options you are loading in the ajax call has a value of `6`. If so then its because the ajax call is asynchronous  and your trying to set the value before the options have been loaded. But the real question is why do you not populate the initial options of the  in the dropdownlist in the controller. A lot of the code you have shown here is unnecessary (could be reduced by at least half)

Comment: @Stephen the set of option loaded change depending on the choice made in the first dropdownlist. Just for reference. Think of it as if the first dropdown holds a fixedlist of countries and the secondone of cities. The list of cities is different for each country and gets loaded when you change the country. If the value of "x", in the example 6, is not present. It is not import to have an option select in the second dropdown.

Comment: My point is rather than calling `UpdateWordkYearDropDown` when the page is first loaded, it should be populated from the controller, and then only when `TenantId` is changed by selecting an option should you call the method to populate the second dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to the suggestion of Jasen I moved all the from the $(document).ready to the function. Hence I took a litle different approach for setting the selected value, that actually does now what I intended to.

The final working code.

```
function UpdateWordkYearDropDown() {
    var $id = $('#TenantId option:selected').attr('value');
    $('#WorkYearId').html('');
    $('#LinkedStaffMemberFilter').attr('data-zatara-tenantid', $id);
    $('.LinkedStaffMemberContainer').remove();
    var $WorkYearId = $('#WorkYearId').attr('data-zatara-workyearid');
    if (typeof $WorkYearId == typeof undefined || $WorkYearId == false) {
        $WorkYearId = "0";
    }
    $.getJSON('/ActivitiesAdmin/_WorkYearsForTenant/' + $id, function (data) {
        $(data).each(function (index, item) {
            if (item.Value == $WorkYearId)
                $('#WorkYearId').append($('<option>', { text: item.Text, value: item.Value, selected: true }));
            else
                $('#WorkYearId').append($('<option>', { text: item.Text, value: item.Value, selected: false }));
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () { UpdateWordkYearDropDown();});

$('#TenantId').change(function () { UpdateWordkYearDropDown(); });
```